# How to run cloned (dual) apps via adb shell

Tags: android, adb, miui

Could someone tell how to run cloned (dual) application via adb shell. The smartphone has MIUI 11 and the app is TelegramX, for example. Application clone emulator is by default.

I get the original application when I try to run the app via:

```
adb shell
monkey -p org.thunderdog.challegram 1
```

The package list tells only this point:

```
package:org.thunderdog.challegram
```

And no hint to the cloned one.

Meanwhile, directory to the clone application is:
***/data/user/999/org.thunderdog.challegram***
instead of
***/data/data/org.thunderdog.challegram*** that original has. Prpbably, it can be helpfull somehow.

I can't find anywhere documentation about how Dual apps are implemented and how to run such apps through adb.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
adb shell
```

Once you’re in an ADB shell, enter the following command:

```
settings get secure clone_app_list
```

If you are already using the App Twin feature, then you should see either one or two package names returned with this command. If you aren’t using this feature, this string will be empty. Now, we will either append to the existing list or create a new list of apps to clone.

```
settings put secure clone_app_list "PACKAGE#1;PACKAGE#2;PACKAGE#3"
```

Source: [1]: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-clone-any-application-with-emuis-app-twin-feature-no-root/